# Convert Tomcat to TomEE by making jars available in classpath?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

I'm developing a JavaEE application, but the deployment server is plain Tomcat.

The TomEE site says,
"[We start with Tomcat, add our jars and configuration and zip up the rest](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html)".

What I want to know is, by following a similar approach, whether it's possible to add the JavaEE jars(ejb-api, jpa-api, openejb, hibernate, etc.) to the application lib folder and deploy it in Tomcat?

Since the jars will be available in the classpath, Tomcat should not have any problems in using them.

Is this a valid approach towards deploying a JavaEE application to Tomcat?

Comment: Why don't you just replace the existing Tomcat with TomEE? Why do the conversion/expansion process yourself? I'd say the most critical part lies in "add _our_ jars and configuration" which as per their a little more detailed description should comprise all the glue code that uses available Tomcat hooks to make JavaEE available. Just dropping the JavaEE jars into the lib directory probably won't work or you'd have to do some ramup etc. yourself.

Comment: @Thomas, I think many existing applications use the Tomcat server and they would be hesitant to replace it with TomEE just for this one application.

Comment: Well, if you have _one_ application that needs to run in TomEE then you could deploy just that one there and have it communicate with the others via REST etc. On the other hand, at least from my experience, people often hesitate to switch web/application servers because they dread the testing that might be needed. However, I'd consider transforming an existing Tomcat to TomEE that great an intrusion into the server in general (especially with the hooks used) that you'd need to do that testing anyways (at least if you don't trust the process right from the start).